# Cannot access teapot room

Tags: candy-box-2

I have unlocked the desert fortress and try to battle the Teapot but when I go into the door my browser stops responding (I'm using Chrome) and I'm forced to force close the tab. Is it as simple as switching my browser or will I need to reset my game?

Comment: Well, you could *try* to switch the browser first. All you need to do is save the game as text on chrome, then copy-paste and load it from text on another browser.